# Unable to retrieve and view results from a SQLite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am trying to build my skills as an iPhone developer, and presently I am working on using the SQLite database.  I have created a SQLite table as follows in my GroceryListAppDelegate.m class:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    self.database = [[[ISDatabase alloc] initWithFileName:@"TestDB.sqlite"] autorelease];

if(![[database tableNames] containsObject:@"GroceryItem"]) {

    [database executeSql:@"create table GroceryItem(primaryKey integer primary key autoincrement, name text NOT NULL, number integer NOT NULL)"];
    [database executeSql:@"insert into GroceryItem (name, number) values ('apples', 5)"];
    [database executeSql:@"insert into GroceryItem (name, number) values ('oranges', 3)"];

}

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

I make a sql call in my RootViewController.m class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

GroceryList1AppDelegate *appDelegate = (GroceryList1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.results = [appDelegate.database executeSqlWithParameters:@"SELECT * from GroceryItem where number < ?", [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], nil];

}
```

My executeSqlWithParameters() method looks like this:

```
- (NSArray *) executeSql:(NSString *)sql withParameters: (NSArray *) parameters {

NSMutableDictionary *queryInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[queryInfo setObject:sql forKey:@"sql"];

if (parameters == nil) {

    parameters = [NSArray array];

}

//we now add the parameters to queryInfo

[queryInfo setObject:parameters forKey:@"parameters"];

NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

//log the parameters

if (logging) {

    NSLog(@"SQL: %@ \n parameters: %@", sql, parameters);

}

sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    [self bindArguments: parameters toStatement: statement queryInfo: queryInfo];

    BOOL needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames = YES;
    NSArray *columnTypes = nil;
    NSArray *columnNames = nil;

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        if (needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames) {

            columnTypes = [self columnTypesForStatement:statement];
            columnNames = [self columnNamesForStatement:statement];
            needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames = NO;

        }

        id row = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [self copyValuesFromStatement:statement toRow:row queryInfo:queryInfo columnTypes:columnTypes columnNames:columnNames];
        [rows addObject:row];
        [row release];

    }       

}

else {

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    [self raiseSqliteException:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"failed to execute statement: '%@', parameters: '%@' with message: ", sql, parameters] stringByAppendingString:@"%S"]];

}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
return rows;

}
```

When I build and run my code, I get no results, when in fact, given my SQL call, I should get apples, and oranges in my list.  However, when I modify my sql code to this:

```
self.results = [appDelegate.database executeSql:@"SELECT * from GroceryItem"];
```

Which calls the different method: executeSql():

```
- (NSArray *) executeSql: (NSString *)sql {

return [self executeSql:sql withParameters: nil];

}
```

In this case, I end up getting the results: apples, and oranges.  Why is this?  What am I doing wrong?  Why is it that I am getting results from one SQL call, and not from another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for all of your help, but I found the solution.  The problem was in my bindArguments() function:

```
- (void) bindArguments: (NSArray *) arguments toStatement: (sqlite3_stmt *) statement queryInfo: (NSDictionary *) queryInfo {
```

right where I had the bind statement for numbers:

```
else if ([argument isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        {
            sqlite3_bind_double(statement, -1, [argument doubleValue]);
        }
```

I needed to change the -1 to an i. This variables tells SQL which variable I am going to susbstitute in the statement. So in this case we only have one variable represented by ? and it should be substituted by a 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the .sqlite file from the Simulator or device and open it in on the command line using `sqlite3`, does the query work?  This will enable you to separate testing your database creation code and query code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  But how would I extract the .sqlite file from the simulator, and open it on the command line using sqlite3?  Thanks again for your help.